# R lm() interaction terms or effect?

Tags: interaction, lm

I have quick look but I do not seem to find the answer to the following question. Basically, I get the following output when I run lm():

```
    Call:
lm(formula = y ~ as.factor(x1) * x2, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-13.7237  -3.4391   0.8872   3.7576   8.3555 

Coefficients:


                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|
(Intercept)                  8.448e+01  1.646e+00  51.318   <2e-16 ***
as.factor(x1)2               5.273e-01  2.967e+00   0.178   0.8597    
as.factor(x1)3               2.442e+00  2.542e+00   0.961   0.3416    
x2                          -3.259e-05  8.820e-05  -0.369   0.7134    
as.factor(x1)2:x2           -2.641e-04  2.636e-04  -1.002   0.3215    
as.factor(x1)3:x2           -2.728e-04  1.314e-04  -2.076   0.0434 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 5.809 on 47 degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.207, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1227 
F-statistic: 2.454 on 5 and 47 DF,  p-value: 0.04683
```

The question is what is the interpretation of regression coefficients? More specifically what do the estimates of interaction mean? For example, is  *-2.728e-04* the interaction term or the effect of x2 on (x1)3?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the individuals with x1 equal to the reference value (here 1), an
increase of x2 by one unit is associated to an increase of y by -3.259e-5.

For the individuals with x1 equal to 3, an increase of x2
by one unit is associated to an increase of y by -3.259e-5 + (-2.728e-4).